# Extracting client certificate & private key from .p12 file

Tags: c, openssl, ssl-certificate, pkcs#12

Can anybody tell me how to use

```
PKCS12 *d2i_PKCS12_fp(FILE *fp, PKCS12 **p12); 

int PKCS12_parse(PKCS12 *p12, const char *pass, EVP_PKEY **pkey, X509 **cert, STACK_OF(X509) **ca);
```

any documenatation reference will also work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without error-checking:

```
FILE *p12_file;
PKCS12 *p12_cert = NULL;
EVP_PKEY *pkey;
X509 *x509_cert;
STACK_OF(X509) *additional_certs = NULL;

p12_file = fopen("foo.p12", "rb");
d2i_PKCS12_fp(p12_file, &p12_cert);
fclose(p12_file);

PKCS12_parse(p12_cert, "password", &pkey, &x509_cert, &additional_certs);
```

The private key is now in `pkey`, the certificate in `x509_cert` and any additional certificates in `additional_certs`.

Comment: When I am using the above code, it is crashing when
d2i_PKCS12_fp(p12_file, &p12_cert); 
is getting executed.

Can anybody tell me why it is happening ?

Comment: @bharat: Sorry, `p12_cert` also needs to be initialised to `NULL` (see updated answer).

Comment: @caf: I think it is initialised to NUll in line #02

Comment: @bharat: It is now, because I fixed it - but it wasn't before, and that was the bug.

Comment: @bharat: Works fine for me... (you can also just do `p12_cert = d2i_PKCS12_fp(p12_file, NULL);` if you like).

Answer (score 2):

- Here is openssl's page for parse: [PKCS12_parse.html](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS12_parse.html)
- Here is Apple's link to using openssl libs: [see PKCS#12, Section 2: I/O](http://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-46/openssl/doc/openssl.txt)

From Apple's site, here are the descriptions:

```
int PKCS12_parse(PKCS12 *p12, char *pass, EVP_PKEY **pkey, X509 **cert,
                             STACK **ca);
```

This function takes a PKCS12 structure and a password (ASCII, null terminated)
    and returns the private key, the corresponding certificate and any CA
    certificates. If any of these is not required it can be passed as a NULL.
    The 'ca' parameter should be either NULL, a pointer to NULL or a valid STACK
    structure. Typically to read in a PKCS#12 file you might do:

```
p12 = d2i_PKCS12_fp(fp, NULL);
PKCS12_parse(p12, password, &pkey, &cert, NULL);    /* CAs not wanted */
PKCS12_free(p12);
```

Comment: This SSLeay site for i2d functions with descriptions was also helpful: http://www.umich.edu/~x509/ssleay/asn1_convert.html