# How to verify the password of a pkcs#12 certificate (.PXF) with openssl C API?

Tags: c, openssl, pkcs#12

I have an .pxf (AFAIK PKCS#12) certificate. How can I confirm a given password for this certificate using the openssl C API?

Comment: See this answer, noting that if PKCS12_parse returns 1, then the password was correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549459/extracting-client-certificate-private-key-from-p12-file

Comment: Also, try using the pkcs12 utility that comes with OpenSSL (http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html).  If that works, look at `<openssl source>/apps/pkcs12.c` to see how they do it.

Comment: @indiv: Post your second comment as an answer and I will accept it :).

Comment: All right.  I was hoping someone would come along and post a better answer than a link, but these OpenSSL questions just don't get many page views around here.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

One approach to finding answers like this is to find an OpenSSL utility that performs the same functionality as what you are trying to do.  In this case, you can use the [pkcs12](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/pkcs12.html) utility that comes with OpenSSL to verify the password.

The command to verify a pfx file is the following:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in mypfx.pfx -noout
```

With that information, you can then look at its [source code](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/pkcs12.c) (`{openssl_src}/apps/pkcs12.c`) to see how they do it.

The source code shows that it calls `PKCS12_verify_mac` to verify the password.  First to verify that there is no password:

```
if( PKCS12_verify_mac(p12, NULL, 0) )
{
    printf("PKCS12 has no password.\n");
}
```

And then if there is a password, verify it by passing it as an argument:

```
if( PKCS12_verify_mac(p12, password, -1) )
{
    printf("PKCS12 password matches.\n");
}
```

OpenSSL also has demos for working with PKCS12 in `openssl/demos/pkcs12`.  The `pkread.c` demo provides an example for parsing a pfx file with a password.

```
EVP_PKEY *pkey;
X509 *cert;
STACK_OF(X509) *ca = NULL;

if (!PKCS12_parse(p12, password, &pkey, &cert, &ca)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing PKCS#12 file\n");
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    exit(1);
}
```

Full example, compiled with `gcc -std=c99 verifypfx.c -o verifypfx -lcrypto`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <openssl/pkcs12.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        const char *password = "mypassword";
        PKCS12 *p12;

        // Load the pfx file.
        FILE *fp = fopen("mypfx.pfx", "rb");
        if( fp == NULL ) { perror("fopen"); return 1; }
        p12 = d2i_PKCS12_fp(fp, NULL);
        fclose(fp);

        OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
        ERR_load_PKCS12_strings();

        if( p12 == NULL ) { ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr); exit(1); }

        // Note:  No password is not the same as zero-length password.  Check for both.
        if( PKCS12_verify_mac(p12, NULL, 0) )
        {
                printf("PKCS12 has no password.\n");
        }
        else if( PKCS12_verify_mac(p12, password, -1) )
        {
                printf("PKCS12 password matches.\n");
        }
        else
        {
                printf("Password not correct.\n");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `PKCS12_verify_mac()`. eg.

```
FILE* f = fopen("myfile.pfx", "rb");
PKCS12* p12 = d2i_PKCS12_fp(f, NULL);
fclose(f);
if (!PKCS12_verify_mac(p12, (char*)"mypassword", strlen("mypassword")))
{
   // handle failure
}
```